# Vala alternatives to Gnome Keyring OAuth access token storage?

Tags: security, oauth, access-token, vala, gnome-keyring-daemon

are there good OAuth access token/secret storage alternatives to Gnome Keyring for Vala? The Gnome Keyring bindings solution is extremely buggy as it yields far too many C-errors to make debugging practical. Additionally, I know relatively little about security, so I'd rather not have to write any encryption algorithms myself--a well-documented, stable library that does it for me would be ideal.

Comment: I use Gnome Keyring in a Vala application and I had to include my own modified VAPI with it - https://github.com/ptomato/googledocs2latex/blob/master/vapi/gnome-keyring-1-mod.vapi - just diff it with the supplied VAPI to see what I changed. I can't remember whether I ever got around to filing a bug on bugzilla.gnome.org or not... :-(

Answer (score 0):

libsecret is the replacement for gnome-keyring, which is being deprecated.  It has Vala bindings distributed with it.  There are examples in the documentation or you can look at the test case: http://git.gnome.org/browse/libsecret/tree/library/tests/test-vala-lang.vala

Also, gnome-keyring now distributes Vala bindings which are based on GObject Introspection, and should be much better than those distributed with valac.